# How to tell what appid my app is using

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm stuck in a slightly weird situation. When our app was first created, nobody really knew what they were doing and I'm trying to clean things up a bit.

In the iOS developer center, it seems that there are two App IDs for my app. I think I can delete one of them, because the other one is the one that is actually being used, but I'm not 100% sure.

Here is the App ID that I think is actually being used in our released app:

[image]

Here is the "other App ID":

[image]

The annoying thing is that the "other App ID" seems to match the bundle ID of the app and xCode seems to be trying to use it as the application-identifier when the app is submitted to the store. I don't want the application identifier to change.

Is it safe to delete the other app id? Can I force xCode to use the correct application identifier? How can I tell which app ID is actually being used by our released app?

Edit:

Why this arose is because after submitting our latest build to the store for testflight, I got this notification:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "My Cool  App". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to
>   correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Potential Loss of Keychain Access - The previous version of software
>   has an application-identifier value of ['ABCDE.MyCoolApp'] and the new
>   version of software being submitted has an application-identifier of
>   ['QWERTY.MyCoolApp']. This will result in a loss of keychain access. 
>       After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>
> Regards, The App Store team

The fact that the application-identifier is changing, and that it appears to be using the "prefix" as part of this value, suggests that it was using the first app ID, but now it is going to use the second.

Comment: check your info.plist file, there you should specify which App ID you're currently using

Comment: @flizana which key would it be? I don't see anything obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have access to login in to the iTunes Connect for that account?  That's what you really need to verify the bundle ID (aka app ID) of the released app.

Login at itunesconnect.apple.com, click on apps, click on your specific app, click on the 'more' tab, click on 'about this app' it will show you the bundle ID being used for the released app.  Feel free to delete the OTHER app ID out of your account.  Not the one in iTunes Connect :)

The bundle ID in your Xcode project can always be modified to match whatever app ID you'd like, as well as you can easily regenerate any necessary provisioning profiles for any app ID. (of course, you should make it match the existing one in iTunesConnect if you want to release an update for that app)

Edit:

It sounds like you've been able to match up the app ID, but not the prefix.  The way prefixes are assigned has changed over the years and now they are all team based.  You can read this technical note and see if it will help you resolve the warning you encountered.

[Developer Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2311/_index.html)

Comment: I think you might be onto something here, but it doesn't quite match up. I added some further info above in "Edit" - the application-identifier value (whatever that is) is changing, and it appears to be using the "Prefix" field from the App ID to make this value.

Comment: In the itunesconnect account, it shows my app as having the bundle ID "MyCoolApp" which matches what I set in xCode, but not the app ID.

Comment: I've added a reference for you to investigate and evaluate the implications of changing your prefix.

Comment: Yes I think that's right - the prefix for the other app ID is the same as my team ID. thanks

Comment: Just to fill in some more details, I found that test flight was not able to update my app from the app store version to the new version, if the new version was using the team ID based APP ID. I don't know if that is just a bug in test flight or what, but I couldn't take the chance, so I modified the xCode generated provisioning profile to use the old App ID, and I no longer seem to have the problem

Answer (score 1):

The primary difference between your 2 App ID is the ID:

- the first one has '*' as ID. It means it is a wildcard ID. You can create multiple applications using different bundle identifiers with the same provisioning profile using this ID. But you don't have access to specific capabilities such as Push Notifications, in-app purchase (because multiple apps will share the same profile
- the second one is fully qualified and can be used only with the app whose bundle identifier is 'MyCoolApp' and can have access to full capabilities of apps.

Note that your app ID naming convention should be in reverse url format as Apple advices: `myCompany.myInternalGroup.myAppId.appFlavor` for instance.

Comment: Given that my app isn't in reverse url format, do you know if it is safe to change it later?

Comment: If you change it, the app will be considered as a new app. It will not replace the old app; it will install next to it, and you won't have access to user data created in the old app. Different bundle identifiers means different apps.